# For GAM in mgcv, if centering at mean in advanced for each group, would the reference point later be respect to the mean for each group?

Tags: r, gam, mgcv

`gam` in `mgcv` performs centering constraint at a common mean if smoothing a covariate for a categorical variable.

If I center the covariate at mean in advanced for each group, doing the analysis via `s(x, by = group)`, and add them back in visualisation, does it mean the reference point is at mean of each group?